# How to make woocommerce generate Unique ID for each product on the cart, this will be used on another mobile app to redeem gift

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a virtual product, which is to purchase a licence for another mobile app.

Now there are several packages so it is not one product, however, the user can still buy 2 or 3 packages in the same order, how do I make wordpress generate IDs for these purchases so it can be used in the other mobile app??

Comment: So a user can add 2 or 3 copies of the same product and you'd like it to generate a unique ID for each?

Comment: THat is a case, and also he can buy 2 or 3 different packages